# SqlDataAdapter.Fill never ends when I use parameters

Tags: parameters, timeout, fill, sqldataadapter

I have a issue when I use parameters in a select query.

```
sqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(con);
cmd.commandText = "SELECT TOP 1 * FROM tbl WHERE SN=@SN"

cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParamter("@SN", "N900"));
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
da.Fill(dt);  // TIMES OUT
```

but when I run it without parameters i works perfect, it takes just 1 second to respond.

```
cmd.commandText = "SELECT TOP 1 * FROM tbl WHERE SN='N900'"
```

Any idea?

I can add that the table is a View.

I figured out, there are two options, 
1. Recompile the View
2. Add at the end of the query "Option (Recompile)"

Answer (score 0):

So I am not sure why it is not working for you. Here is a simple example below that I know works.

```
var sqlCommand = new SqlCommand();
sqlCommand.Connection = new SqlConnection("<YOUR_CONNECTION_STRING>");

sqlCommand.CommandText = @"SELECT * FROM (SELECT 'N900' as SN
                            UNION 
                            SELECT 'N901') AS A
                            WHERE A.SN = @SN";

sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@SN", "N900"));
var sqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCommand);

var dataTable = new DataTable();

sqlDataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out, there are two options, 
1. Recompile the View 
2. Add at the end of the query "Option (Recompile)"